# How does this extension property to capitalize the first letter of every word in a string work?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, capitalize

I'm recently trying to get into kotlin (coming from java) and did some beginner coding challenges.

**The task is to write a function that capitalizes the first letter of every word in a string**

I could solve the task in my own way, but I still don't understand this sample solution:

```
fun capitalizeSentence(str: String) {
     println(str.split(" ").joinToString(" ") { it.capitalize() })
}
```

**Can someone explain to me, why this lambda expressions manages to capitalize the first letter of every word, even when using the joinToString method right after the split method?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`joinToString()` accepts an optional `transform` function which it applies to each item **before** joining. It might be confusing to you, because this code performs operations in a different order than the code flow itself. This code is effectively an equivalent of this one:

```
str.split(" ")
    .map { it.capitalize() }
    .joinToString(" ")
```